Unkown Display after install nvidia-driver-470 on Ubuntu 22.04
I tried the answers posted in the links below:
Extra unknown display is showing up
Ubuntu Detects 2 monitors when I only have one This works but i am no longer able to start a wayland session.  Actually this is a separate problem.
I installed nvidia-driver-470 and after restarting, my login screen and desktop seem to act as a dual screen monitor.  If i slide my mouse over to the right edge it will scroll the background and windows.  If i go to the Display settings, I have two displays an unknown display and my display.  I only have one physical monitor and I am assuming this is a driver issue but i don't have enough experience to figure this out on my own.
I was able to set my monitor to a single display but the unknown display is still present.  switching to the unknown display results in a black screen.
I tried to set the nvidia_drm module modeset parameter to one in /etc/modprobe.d/myconfig.conf that did not fix the issue.
xrandr -q gives
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 520mm x 320mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  74.97    59.94    50.00    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1366x768      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93  
None-1-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00 +


Oh you are not the only one who has ghost monitors. Can you try if nvidia-drm.modeset=1 as kernelbootoption is working?

@nobody what does setting that do?  Also what do you mean by "as kernelbootoption is working"

I am assuming i write this option to a file.  which one?
https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter
I'll try this.

that did not work.

okay please choose in your displaymanager X11(Xorg session) Does this error persist then?

@nobody If i reinstall xorg it is no longer an issue.  but it persists if i use nvidia-driver-470 and nvidia-driver-390 just will not install at all.

This question is similar to: How do disable/get rid of PRIME display?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Okay I found something in arch wiki I hope it works in ubuntu too (I can not trigger this error on my system)
Please create file
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf

With following content.
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "None-1-1"
    Option "Ignore" "true"
EndSection

inspiration
